# ObservedObject not working when getting data async for view

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm

Using StateObject allows my view to rerender correctly after getting data asynchronously but ObservedObject does not, why?

I have two swiftui views. First is the root App view and the second is the one consuming an ObservedObject view model.

From the root view I create a ViewModel with a firebase object ID for the second view and pass it in. When the second view appears I'd like to then send a request to Firebase to retrieve some data. While the data is being retrieved I show a 'loading' screen.

When I use ObservedObject my second view never rerenders after the data is retrieved. Using StateObject though fixes the issue but I'm not sure why.

I think I understand the differences between ObservedObject and StateObject having read the docs. But not sure how the differences apply to my case since I don't think the root view should be rerendering and recreating the ViewModel I created there and passed to the second view.

There is a Login view which forces the RootView to rerender after login but from what I know, the SecondView still shouldn't be rendered more than once.

https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/stateobject-observedobject-differences/

RootView

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @ObservedObject private var userService = UserService()
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                Group {
                    if (userService.currentUser != nil) {
                        SecondView(secondViewModel: SecondViewModel(somethingId: "someIdGoesHere"))
                    } else {
                        LoginView()
                    }
                }
                .environmentObject(userService)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View Model

```
class SecondViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var thing: Thing? = nil
    private let thingService = ThingService()
    private let thingId: String
    
    init(thingId: String) {
        self.thingId = thingId
    }
    
    func load() async {
        self.thing = await thingService.GetThing(thingId: thingId) // Async call to firebase
    }
}
```

Second View

```
struct SecondView: View {
 
    // Task runs to completion but 'Loading...' never goes away.
    @ObservedObject var secondViewModel: SecondViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 5) {
            if let thingText = secondViewModel.thing {
                Text(thingText)
            } else {
                Text("Loading...")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                await secondViewModel.load()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the SWiftUI component of Instruments to see how many times a view is being re-rendered.

Comment: It seems fine (except I don't understand how `let thingText = secondViewModel.thing` would succeed, but it may be irrelevant)... Try maybe making it non-optional, e.g `@Published private(set) var thing: Thing = .dummy` where `dummy` is something you can identify as "no data, still loading"

Comment: There are a lot of articles on the differences of the two. ObservedObject doesn’t have a way to retain an object it needs a parent that does.

Comment: If you use `.task` for your async code and set the result on `@State` you can remove the need for an object entirely.